How to center row text vertically in the tkinter Treeview widget?
My problem is that in the example below, the text in the highlighted row is positioned at the top and is not vertically centered.
I would like to achieve the same effect as with the CSS attribute "vertical-align: middle".
import tkinter as tk
from  tkinter import ttk, font

class SampleTreeView:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    columns = ('ord', 'char')
    font_size = 16
    view_font = font.Font(family = 'Times', size = font_size, slant = font.ROMAN)
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure('Sample.Treeview', font = view_font, rowheight = round(font_size * 1.5))
    #style.configure('Sample.Treeview.field', anchor = tk.CENTER)
    self._tree = ttk.Treeview(parent, style = 'Sample.Treeview', columns = columns, selectmode = tk.BROWSE, show = '', padding = (0, 0, 0, 0))
    self._tree.column('#0', width = 0, stretch = tk.NO)
    col_widths = [0] * 2
    for i in range(4):
      c = chr(i + 97)
      t = (str(ord(c)), c)
      for j in range(2):
        col_widths[j] = max(col_widths[j], view_font.measure(t[j]))
      self._tree.insert(parent = '', index = tk.END, iid = i, text = '', values = t)
    for j in range(2):
      w = round(col_widths[j] * 1.5)
      self._tree.column(columns[j], anchor = tk.CENTER, minwidth = w, width = w, stretch = tk.NO)
    self._tree.pack(side = tk.LEFT, expand = True, fill = tk.Y)
    self._tree.selection_set(3)

root = tk.Tk()
tv = SampleTreeView(root)
root.mainloop()

Version tkinter: 8.6.14 (Linux)
SampleTreeView
UPD:
In the comments, someone pointed out that the letter "g" could look more vertically centered. Therefore, I have decided to provide screenshot from a real application instead of a minimal reproducible sample.

tkinter 8.6.13 on Windows 10 shows the rows horizontaly centered. What OS are you using?

Thank you for clarification. I add OS to the post, but I asked about vertically, not about horizontaly.

I'm sorry, I meant vertically. Tested on Windows and now on Linux Ubuntu 24.04 with tkinter 8.6.14. Both are aligned in the vertical center of the field (unlike your screenshot). What distro and python version are you using?

Arch, Python 3.12.4

If changing d to g, then it may look center vertically.

Since there is Chinese (maybe Japanese) characters inside the text, try using appropriate font instead of Times.

Tested your code on Arch with Gnome, looks perfect with US system locals.

On this question, I learned that before using a font, you need to make sure that it is in your system. For example, this answer helped me figure it out.
After changing the font selection line to
view_font = font.Font(family = 'Times New Roman', size = font_size)

the problem with vertical alignment in my system was solved.
Thank you all for your help.
